# Silverlight MVVM Unit-Testing Explanation

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, mvvm

Can anyone explain why, when I step through my unit tests with the debugger, that I get null references whenlooking at objects or properties. For example:

```
1      [TestMethod]
2            [Description("Test to confirm that upon initial class creation, the login view is loaded as the default content for the TaskRegion.")]
3            public void Shell_Initialisation_LoginViewIsLoadedByDefault()
4            {
5                Shell shell = new Shell();
6    
7                TestPanel.Children.Add(shell);
8    
9                Shell_ViewModel viewModel = shell.DataContext as Shell_ViewModel;
10   
11               Assert.IsTrue(viewModel.TaskRegionContent is ContentControl);
12   
13               EnqueueTestComplete();
14           }
```

[Line 9] When I set my viewModel field to the DataContext of the shell view I get a "object not set to instance..." exception. I know for sure that my datacontext is being set in my shell.xaml.cs; entire file:

```
1    using System.Windows;
2    
3    namespace eg.WorkManager.UI.Shell
4    {
5        public partial class Shell
6        {
7    
8            public Shell()
9            {
10               InitializeComponent();
11               this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Shell_Loaded);
12           }
13   
14           void Shell_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
15           {
16               this.DataContext = new Shell_ViewModel();
17           }
18       }
19   }
20
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but can anyone explain what?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that the problem is that you are instantiating the Shell object in isolation.  Have you confirmed that Shell_Loaded (the Loaded event) is even being called?

Why are you not creating your view model as a static resource in your xaml?  With MVVM, I usually create it as a static resource in the xaml and then bind it as the data context in the LayoutRoot... all in xaml.

Comment: I'm a developer, old habits die hard ;-) I'll try that and see if I get better results. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the `DataContext` during the `Loaded` event, which is raised when your control is actually loaded into the visual tree. Therefore, your `DataContext` won't be set because all you've done is constructed the view. You can easily verify by running your unit tests with a debugger attached and setting a breakpoint in the `Loaded` handler.

Comment: So I tried using Justin Angels idea of a WaitFor() method, that uses an EnqueueConditional to wait for the Loaded event to fire. I still don't see the concrete objects so I removed that for simplicity.

Comment: Loaded will likely not fire under a unit test. As Kent mentioned, Loaded only happens when an element is added to the visual tree. Unless your unit test actually displays the shell, Loaded will not fire.